# How to use ntlm with out browser login-password form?

Tags: php, laravel, ntlm

```
public function ntlm()
    {
            $headers = apache_request_headers();
            if (isset($headers['Authorization']))
            {
                $auth = $headers['Authorization'];
            }


            if (isset($auth) && substr($auth,0,5) == 'NTLM ') 
            {
                 $msg = base64_decode(substr($auth, 5));

                 if (substr($msg, 0, 8) != "NTLMSSP\x00")
                 { 
                  return false;
                 }

                 if ($msg[8] == "\x01") 
                 {
                        $msg2 = "NTLMSSP\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00".
                            "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name len/alloc
                        "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name offset
                        "\x01\x02\x81\x00". // flags
                        "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // challenge
                        "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // context
                        "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; // target info len/alloc/offset

                    return false;
                 }
                 else if ($msg[8] == "\x03") 
                 {

                    $username = $this->get_msg_str($msg, 36);
                    $domain = $this->get_msg_str($msg, 28);
                    $workstation = $this->get_msg_str($msg, 44);
                    return  $username;
                 }
           }

           return false;
    }
```

This on top laravel

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
  exit; //this is just php request
}
```

When i use this code if i dont have response from server(like login - yerzhanov_a)(when i in corp network i have AD account), when i use another computer and network my code ntlm doesnt have response and show me login-password browser form!
How to remove this form or hide and just have redirect on auth page?

Comment: Add the code snippet, not the image.

Comment: check @Dino i added code not image